# Use ArrayBuffer in sequentially executed Threads?

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency, future, arraybuffer

I have two `Future`s, the second of which starts after the first ended. Both write to the same `ArrayBuffer` instance, but since they are executed serially (not at the same time), I consider them not acting concurrently.

However, I know there is the `@volatile` annotation for variables shared among two or more threads (`@volatile` disables caching).

Since after the first thread finishes, inside the `ArrayBuffer` instance, there might be some **caching** going on that makes it impossible for the second thread to see the `ArrayBuffer`'s real state: I am not sure whether it is safe to use `ArrayBuffer` this way.

**Is it true that caching might be a problem in my situation, and if this is the case: Is there a recommended way to make `ArrayBuffer` use `@volatile` internally?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be fine iff (if-and-only-if) you propagate it [the array] through the future:

```
val futureA = Future {
  val buf = ArrayBuffer(…)
  update(buf)
  buf
}

val futureB = futureA map {
  buf => moreUpdates(buf); buf
}

futureB foreach println // print the result of the transformations
```

This is OK from a memory safety point of view because the completion of `futureA` [happens-before](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) the `onComplete` (virtually all transformations on Future is implemented on top of `onComplete`) callback is invoked. In this case `map`.

Comment: Unfortunately, currently this is not the case: The `ArrayBuffer` "visits" the two threads through two callbacks for each file. Hence, the `ArrayBuffer` sees no difference between the two threads. But the second thread (the second future) is started by the first future's `onComplete`.

Comment: Why onComplete and not flatMap?

Comment: Since `onComplete` is sufficient for my needs. In which respect is this relevant to my question?

Comment: It is relevant to your question because if you use flatMap the way I show above, it'll work. In general, you should avoid using the callbacks and use the transformations instead, since thrown exceptions in the callbacks will not be visible.

Comment: The callbacks contain custom UI code that is executed on the user interface thread (for each processed file). To me, it is not clear how I can achieve this without using callbacks. This hindered me from using something else.

Comment: Seems easy enough if you create an execution context which you run in the interface thread for the ops which needs it. https://gist.github.com/viktorklang/2422659

Comment: If I understand it correctly, this execution context enables me to execute code on the UI thread from within the worker thread classes. That is not what I intend, since the worker classes should never deal with UI related code. For me it is very important to separate workers and UI. That is why I use callbacks that are passed to the worker objects when the UI invokes their methods.

Comment: Can you give me a cite that supports your statement concerning the _happens-before_ relation for `Future` & `onComplete`? I was not able to find anything about it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not caching, per se, but the fact that an `ArrayBuffer` is a composite, with several subfields that have to be updated in concert to assure correct operation. You will need to use thread synchronization tools to ensure this.

```
class ArrayBufferWrapper[T](ab: ArrayBuffer[T]) {
  def add(item: T) = {
    this.synchronized {
      ab.add(item)
    }
  }
}
```

By wrapping the `ArrayBuffer`, the components are properly realized into the current thread, and you ensure thread-safe `add` operations.

Comment: Couldn't I simply use a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not safe.

This is exactly the reason why they invented functional programming. If you are using scala anyway, might as well take advantage of the paradigm it offers.

Avoid using mutable structures, or, at least, in the rare cases when you have to use them, do not let them escape the local scope. Then you won't ever have to deal with problems like this. They just will not exist anymore.

Tell us more about what you are trying to do, and  i am sure someone will suggest a design or two, not involving two threads mutating the same structure.

Comment: The first future collects thousands of files and appends them to the array buffer. The second future finds further files and appends them as well. I could just export an immutable represenation of the array buffer after the first future is done, and let it act in a functional manner that way. But I am afraid this is an unnecessarily expensive copying around of huge amounts of data...

Comment: Btw. it is wrong that not exiting the local scope saves me from having to deal with problems like this: the `ArrayBuffer` instance never ever is accessed from outside the local scope, rather the local scope stretches over three different threads.

Comment: Why are they sequential to begin with? It sounds like something like this should work: `Future { findFiles } zip Future { findMoreFiles } map { case (a,b) => a ++ b }`

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't `a ++ b` a huge operation that I better avoid if, say, `a` contains 1 million files and `b` contains another million?

Comment: Depends  on the kind of collection you use. `Stream` concatenation for example is "free". (It doesn't matter (much) what your futures actually return, as you can always just do `a.toStream ++ b.toStream`

Comment: (I am not primarily using Scala because it provides me with functional programming, hence it does not matter to me that bad performance tells me I should not use it in a purely functional manner. Still I avoid `var` and `mutable` where ever possible because it easier to me to follow the flow of immutables.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to `Stream`. If I understand it right, it can let me avoid `ArrayBuffer` entirely without having to fear performance impacts.

Comment: Bad performance is a result of bad design and bad implementation, not of using one or another programming paradigm. Yes, you do not need ArrayBuffer for this. And you do not need your futures to be sequential.

Comment: I never said I need my futures to be sequential. They simply *are* sequential, because the second future depends on the first future's result. Apart from that I agree with you.

Comment: What is still unclear to me: How can I produce a robust optional error stream? I need to put the errors into an intermediate queue and hope a client thread reads the stream, otherwise the queue grows and grows (unnecessarily). To me, this seems not as straightforward as just using plain old callbacks (because I have to maintain a queue that can be read through the stream plus I need to decide whether errors are going to be processed and thence they must be put on a queue or not).

Comment: Use callbacks then ... what does it have to do with anything?